# how to change the year of birth to age in .sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql file containing `bYear` and `u_age` column in `users` table.

I would like to know how I can change all the digits in `bYear`, such as `1986`, `2000`, to `u_age` such as `33`, `19`.

Thanks so much !!

Comment: Do you want to update a *file* or a *table*?

Comment: to add to @GMB 's comment.. Don't even start updating a `.sql` file , import the `.sql` into a MySQL table, Run a `UPDATE` or multiple `UPDATE`s and export that table to a `.sql` file...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to update the table (not the *file*), you can just do:

```
update users set u_age = year(curdate()) - bYear;
```

`curdate()` gives you the current date, from which you can extract the year using the `year()` function.

Please note that this computation is not accurate at all: to compute an age, you need the entire date of birth (including month and day). The above computation behaves like the date of birth is actually the first day of year `bYear`.

If you are looking to update a sql file: as commented by Raymond Nijland, just don't. This is much more complicated and far less efficient. Instead, load the file in a table, update the table and then export it to a file